# Writing debug logs of SQLite operations in UWP C# (sqlite-net)

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, windows-runtime, sqlite-net

Are there any possibilities to write logs of every SQLite operations in UWP Windows 10 apps. Are there any inbuilt logging methods? I'm using [sqlite-net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net/) library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Metro logs for UWP apps refer - https://github.com/onovotny/MetroLog

Comment: Exactly, metro logs can be used in Windows 10 UWP apps. I have also used them, feel free if any help is required

Comment: Has it helped you?

Comment: I will try and get back to you very soon. Thank you.Will vote you up.